# Use sans serif math operators with Roboto

Tags: fonts, mathspec, kpfonts, math-fonts

[Thanks to @HenriMenke](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/394336/8425), I know how to use [Roboto font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto) in math for letters (including Greek) and digits. Now, I'd like to use a sans serif font for math operators as well (say `\int` or `\sum`). AFAIK, Roboto does not provide such glyphs.

How can I do (I mostly use `lualatex` but I can use `xelatex` if necessary)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use e.g. Fira Math:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{roboto}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Fira Math}
\setmathfont[range=up]{Roboto}
\setmathfont[range=it]{Roboto-Italic}
\setmathfont[range=\int]{Fira Math}

\begin{document}
 Hello world! 12345 $12345$

 \textit{abcdef} $abcdef$

 $\gamma = G$
  \[\int \sum  a^2 + b^2 = c^2 \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great (+1), thanks. That's clearly a very good alternative I did not think of at that time. But what's the problem with kpfonts? Is it too complex with non otf fonts?

Comment: Why should I spent a lot of time trying to figure out how to at best mix legacy math fonts (kpfonts) with opentype font (roboto) when there exist sans-serif math fonts now?

Comment: Sorry. No offense intented. So I guess the answer is: yes it is complex to mix legacy fonts and otf. It does not worth it. Thanks again.